# Excel Text Format Number to round to millions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to imbed a number in a text string, while still rounding it to millions and showing an 'm'?

If it was just formatting, I would use:

```
#.#,, 'm'
```

and in text I would use:

```
text(ref, "#.#,,")
```

but how can you combine the two? the below does not work

```
text(ref, "#.#,,m")
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what number format you are converting and what you want it to look like?

Comment: I'd like to round to the million with decimal, so 15,100,000 would show was 15.1m

Comment: Is it just to one decimal place? So for example `15,199,999` would be `15.2m`?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I'm after

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
=TEXT(ROUND(ref,-6)/1000000,"#,##0")&"m"
```

This would round a number up to millions and then replace the 6 `0's` with the letter 'm'. e.g. `4,658,458,685` would become:

`4,658m`

Edit:

The following works as requested with everything inside the `TEXT` function:

```
 =TEXT(ref, "#.#,," & """m""")
```

Comment: is there a way to include the "m" in the text formatting though? text(ref,"#.#,,") would already show the figure as 4.658, all that's missing is the m and I'd rather include it in the formatting than the rest of the text string if possible

Comment: works perfect, thank you! Could you explain why the 2 sets of four quotation marks are necessary though, what is that doing?

Comment: Basically they're adding an additional quotation mark as a string; each set of 4 quotation marks is just one quotation mark as a string. So for example if you were trying to create the value `"m"` (where the actual value of the sell includes the quotation marks and not just `m`) in a cell you could do: `=""""&"m"&""""` because you can't put 3 sets of quotation marks in a row as excel thinks you haven't finished writing a string.

Comment: You're basically putting the format as 4 separate strings: `#.#,,` then `"` then `m` then `"`

Comment: The following also works and has a few less quotes:  `=TEXT(ref, "#.#,," & """m""")`

Comment: @Jordan Any idea why either of the #s in the this formula are not shown when the # is 0?

`=TEXT(ref, "#.#,," & """m""")`